# Updating profile pic of user but its not requesting user to upload the pic

Tags: python, html, django

> I want to update the profile pic of the user in the database, But its not requesting the user to upload the pic, on clicking the upload button its simply redirecting me to the page.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class userprofile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    profilepic = models.ImageField(default='pp.png',upload_to='profile_pic',blank = True)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import userprofile



class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = userprofile
        fields = ['profilepic',]
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def profile(request):    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=request.user.userprofile)
        if p_form.is_valid():
            p_form.save()        
            return render(request,'profile.html')
    else:
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.userprofile)

    context = {
        'p_form': p_form        
        }

    return render(request,'profile.html',context)
```

**profile.html**

```
<form method ="POST" class="sm:w-1/3 text-center sm:pr-8 sm:py-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ p_form|crispy }}

            <input style="padding: 8px 93px;" class="text-white bg-green-500 border-0 py-2 px-8 focus:outline-none hover:bg-green-700 rounded text-lg" type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
<img id="profile_pic" alt="team" class="flex-shrink-0 rounded-lg w-full h-56 object-cover object-center mb-4" src="{{user.userprofile.profilepic.url}}">
```

Comment: Why you put html img and input? That this done the 'p_form'

Comment: what should I write then?

Comment: img tag is to show the image of the user and input button is for requesting user to update the pic by selecting from their device.

Comment: Only with this {{ p_form|crispy }} should work

Comment: I did the same but its not working. Now there is no such button to upload the pic too

Comment: and without crispy?

Comment: same issue not working

Comment: Are you checked all topics? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/ https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform

Comment: ya i went through it but still there is some issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forget to add the context when rendering

```
return render(request,'profile.html', context)
```

[image]

Comment: i got error doing this:
UnboundLocalError at /profile/
local variable 'context' referenced before assignment

Comment: You have defined context in the if request.method == 'POST' branch, but not in the else branch. Therefore you get an error for GET requests. Get the context out of the if statement. Make it align with if statement.

Comment: i did the same but still ther's error
UnboundLocalError at /profile/
local variable 'p_form' referenced before assignment

Comment: well you did some indentation error. I have attached an snippet in my answer above refer for any indentation error.

Comment: yes i did the same but its not requesting the user to upload the pic. Its just rendering me to the homepage.

Comment: why are you rendering the home page when the form is valid return render(request,'test_homepage.html'). remove that line of code cause you need to redirect the user somewhere on submit

Comment: I did the same but its not asking image to upload from device. It stays on the same page

Comment: First thing, is the form being rendered?

Comment: ok.. you are missing a comma here in your forms.py  fields = ['profilepic',]

Comment: Added the comma. Still the same issue

Comment: I just want after clicking the upload button the user can upload the pic from their device.

Comment: can you once update your question with your updated code.Let me see your code.

Comment: when you save the form dont render the html page return render(request,'profile.html'). You redirect to some page. Remove that line of code and try if the pick is saving in database

Comment: Not working. the issue is on clicking on the upload button its not requesting the user to upload the pic, its simply like refreshing the page.

Comment: ohh!!! do you see the <img> tag in your profile.html. you need to load that image outside the outside the <form> tag after the image is uploaded.

Comment: I have updated my profile.html its still not working.

Comment: The issue is its not populating to upload a pic from device after the upload button is clicked.

Comment: Wat was the issue